# Как обновить opkg без интернета?

Tags: ssh, putty, openwrt, winscp

Мне нужно обновить opkg на моем роутере с прошивкой OpenWrt. Так, гугл подсказывает

```
opkg update
```

Стоп, как же я его обновлю, если у меня нет интернета, так как я не установил пакет, который в свою очередь не устанавливается из-за того, что я не обновил opkg и не установи пакет... Замкнутый круг какой-то.

Так-с. Попробуем подключиться к роутеру не через LAN, а через WIFI. Как раз будет свободный разъем. Через этот то разъем я и получу доступ к интернету. Так-с, какого черта не может получить доступ к интернету. Как это получается, если на ноуте через LAN разъем доступ в интернет есть, а при вводе команды (смотри выше) доступа в инет нету?

Сопственна вопрос. Как мне обновить opkg, не имея доступ в интернет?

С установкой других пакетов я разобрался, я просто скачивал нужный файл и через scp его перекидывал. Может быть, тут что-то подобное будет?

Comment: см. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg ; 1. скачать и распаковать списки пакетов из подключенных у вас репозиториев. 2. получить список того, что можно обновить: `opkg list-upgradable`. 3. скачать всё это и установить.

Comment: другой вариант, «раскрутка». 1. скачайте и попробуйте установить тот пакет, который вам нужен. 2. если не устанавливается, то *opkg* напишет, какие пакеты отсутствуют или «не той версии». 3. для каждого пакета повторите шаги, начиная с первого.